# How do I jsdoc'ument a function parameter with properties in Eclipse IDE content assist?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, editor, autosuggest, jsdoc

According to the [jsdoc documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties), I can do:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} args - Arguments
 * @param {Object} args.req - The request
 * @param {array} args.test - Something array'ish
 */
function doSomething(args) {
    // ...
}
```

Now when I start to type `args.` I get all the object prototype functions in the content assist popup, because of the first `jsdoc` `@param` entry.

However, there is no `req` or `test` in the list of proposals. How do I get these to show up, without having to redeclare `args` within every function using `@type`?

Comment: I have created an ternjs issue for that https://github.com/ternjs/tern/issues/673 If this feature will be implemented, you will able to install tern.java